# keytool : keytool error: what shout I put in place of $keystoredir

Tags: openssl, keytool, lets-encrypt

I want to import a **keytool**:

I execute this commande:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in $certdir/fullchain.pem -inkey          
$certdir/privkey.pem -out $certdir/cert_and_key.p12 -name tomcat
-CAfile $certdir/chain.pem -caname root -password pass:aaa
```

Then I execute this :

```
keytool -importkeystore -srcstorepass aaa -deststorepass changeit
-destkeypass changeit -srckeystore $certdir/cert_and_key.p12 -srcstoretype  
 PKCS12 -alias tomcat -keystore $keystoredir
```

I want to know what I should add in place of **$keystoredir** , because I put the path where the list of certif are generated , I got this :

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
mypath (Is a directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-keystore` argument takes in the KeyStore file location, not a directory (like you did for the `-srckeystore`).

You can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response, in place of the directory i put the $path/cert_and_key.p12 and it works perfectly